# swi-cs-pl create engine with resource file

Tags: c#, ffi, swi-prolog

I have created my prolog file before hand and I want to call it on my c# project through the `SbsSW.SwiPlCs` library, so I added the prolog file to my Resources project folder (`vuelos.pl`).

So far I have the following code:

```
private String file = "Properties.Resources.vuelos";
        public Prolog()
        {
            //read file
            String[] param = { "-q", "-f", file};

            try
            {
                PlEngine.Initialize(param);
                //get my Objects
                using (PlQuery q = new PlQuery("aeropuerto(ID,NAME)"))
                {
                    //I do stuff here (omitted)
                }
            }
            catch (PlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.MessagePl);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                PlEngine.PlCleanup();
            }
        }
```

But it throws a `ResourceNotFoundException` and I don't know how to call my file and I don't want to use an Absolute Path, but if there is any other solution I'd like to hear it.

Comment: So you have `/Applicationfolder/resources/` folder in which the pl files are residing and you want to build a string which shows the actual path to that file?

Comment: Yes, exactly, so far as I know the only way to create a `PlEngine` is with a path to a .pl file.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the Resources Folder is always in the project folder and thus relative to your executable.

If you are using WinForms you can get the Application Path using `Application.StartupPath` and then combine it with your filepath.

Your code should looke like this then:

```
string ApplicationPath = Application.StartupPath;
var plFullPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationPath, @"Resources\vuelos.pl");

//read file
String[] param = { "-q", "-f", plFullPath};
```

Or if you want it all in one line:

```
String[] param = { "-q", "-f", Path.Combine(ApplicationPath, @"Resources\vuelos.pl")};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried this solution and even though the path now is correct and I the vuelos.pl is there I still get a FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 1):

Check you environment variables. If you're using Lesta's library, it only supports prolog version 6.6.5, that could be a problem too.

Answer (score 0):

As *user4794198* mentioned, the current swi-prolog c# library I was using was not compatible with SWI-prolog 6.6.6, so I downloaded the 6.6.5 version.
Additionally, I moved my `vuelos.pl` file from `\Resources` to the root folder of my .exe file (under the `\debug` folder) and made the following call on c#

```
 public Prolog()
    {
        //read file
        try
        {
            PlEngine.Initialize(new Object[]);
            //get my Objects

            PlQuery.PlCall("consult(vuelos)"); //HERE IS THE CHANGE

            using (PlQuery q = new PlQuery("aeropuerto(ID,NAME)"))
            {
                //I do stuff here (omitted)
            }
        }
        catch (PlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.MessagePl);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            PlEngine.PlCleanup();
        }
    }
```

Remember that in order for this to work you should be referencing `SbsSW.SwiPlCs.dll` on it's most updated version and it's architecture should be the same of your installed SWI-Prolog.

If you're on a 64-bit system remember to rename the `SwiPlCs64.dll` from your downloaded .zip file to `SwiPlCs.dll` BEFORE referencing it to your project, as if you do it after or change the name and replace the original `SwiPlCs.dll` it might create some bad references on your project and throw a `BadImageException`.